# Regular expression match a sentence with specified word in a specified distance

Tags: regex

How to match a sentence with Bacon and meat with distance of 2 or less than 2 words?

```
Bacon is thinly sliced lean pork meat ----Reject

Bacon is pork meat    ----Match
```

I have tried:

```
^(\bBacon\b)(\040){1,2}(\bmeat\b)$   => i try to match with the "space" between but it's not working
^(?=.*?\bBacon\b)(?=.*?\bmeat\b).*$  => this will match everything in between regardless the distance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
^Bacon(\s\w+)?(\s\w+)?\smeat$
```

You can see this live [here](https://regex101.com/r/t6mGpF/3).

Out of these:

```
Bacon is thinly sliced lean pork meat
Bacon is meat
Bacon is pork meat
Bacon meat
Bacon is not a meat
```

It finds these:

```
Bacon is meat
Bacon is pork meat
Bacon meat
```

**EDIT:**

This can be shortened to (Live [here](https://regex101.com/r/t6mGpF/5)):

```
^Bacon(\s\w+){0,2}\smeat$
```

Where the `{0,2}` means between 0 and 2 times. Changing to `{0,3}` would mean `Bacon is not a meat` would also be matched.

**EDIT 2:**

To match the `,` as well (Optional comma), (See it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/t6mGpF/7)):

```
^Bacon\,?(\s\w+){0,2}\smeat$
```

Out of these:

```
Bacon is thinly sliced lean pork meat
Bacon is meat
Bacon is pork meat
Bacon meat
Bacon, is meat
Bacon, is pork meat
Bacon, meat
Bacon, is not a meat
Bacon is not a meat
Bacon
Bacon is
```

These are matched:

```
Bacon is meat
Bacon is pork meat
Bacon meat
Bacon, is meat
Bacon, is pork meat
Bacon, meat
```

Comment: May i ask how to match "Bacon, is meat" ?

Comment: @YoongKangLim As in, you want to match `Bacon, is meat`, whilst still matching all the current ones - the comma is optional?

Comment: the comma is optional

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
^.*\bBacon\b\s(\w+\s){0,2}\bmeat\b.*$

Bacon is pork meat  --match
Bacon is thinly sliced lean pork meat  --reject
Bacon meat  --match
Bacon is meat  --match
Bacon is tasty meat  --match
Bacon is not tasty meat  --reject
```